# All files and folders becomes "Read only"

Tags: 14.04, read-only

All my files and folders shows lock symbol few minutes after I turn on my system and I cannot edit any of these files as it says `cannot save: read only file system`. However if I restart the system again, everything works fine for few minutes/hours. While the system is starting, it says something like `remounting /tmp`. How do I resolve this issue ?

Comment: Could you [edit] your question and add the output of `mount | grep /dev/sd` from when the system is still working normally and from when it became read-only?

Comment: Could you provide above information, please?

Answer (score 5):

When system, detects a Hard Disk error, it automatically get into 'read only' mode to protect its files. So first of all try to check your disk and fix any bad sectors, then check the conditions of your disk (e.g SMART), to see if you need to replace it.

Check this resource, it may be helpful

- [Check your hard disk for problems](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/disk-check.html)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried checking for bad blocks in your hard disk?

```
sudo badblocks -v /dev/sda_
```

> Note: Replace `_` with *location* you want to check.

E.g.:

```
sudo badblocks -v /dev/sda1
```

For me the read only happened due to bad blocks in my hard drive.

What is the final fix?

**REPLACE THE HARD DISK**